# If $T\colon V\to V$ and $T=S^*S$ then all eigenvalues of $T$ are non-negative? ($S^*$ is adjoint)

Tags: linear-algebra

If $T\colon V\to V$ and $T=S^*S$ then all eigenvalues of $T$ are non-negative?
($S^*$ is the adjoint to $S$).

Answer (score 1):

Let $Tv=\lambda v$ .Note that $T$ is hermitian so $\lambda\in R$.

$\left<v,Tv\right>=\left<v,\lambda v\right>=\lambda\left<v,v\right>$

and $\left<v,Tv\right>=\left<v,S^*Sv\right>=\left<Sv,Sv\right>$

As $\left<v,v\right>>0$ if $v\ne 0$ and as $v$ is an eigen vector so $v\ne 0\Rightarrow \left<v,v\right>>0$

$\Rightarrow \lambda =\left<Sv,Sv\right>/\left<v,v\right>\ge0$ as $\left<Sv,Sv\right>\ge 0$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Let $Tv = \lambda v$. Then $$\lambda(v,v) = (\lambda v,v) = (Tv,v)= (S^*Sv, v) = (Sv, Sv). $$